# Size of AlertDialogue

Tags: android

How to change the size of the alert Dialogue box??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom layout for your dialog:

```
 FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
 fl.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

See more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).